# Why is converting from RAID1 to single in Btrfs an I/O-intensive operation?

Tags: raid-1, btrfs

I want to replace a device in a RAID1 and converted it temporarily to “single”:

```
btrfs balance start -f -mconvert=single,soft -dconvert=single,soft /
```

This takes very long.  I don’t see why, and wonder whether this is the right approach in the first place.  After all, no (significant) amount of data should be needed to be transferred in the process, should it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an [answer on the Btrfs mailing list](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-btrfs/04ddea4e-4823-00dc-c32c-700d9f7e1fef@libero.it/T/#mf485b2d4934bd264802932f11eb5136f11a0cc88):

> Converting between RAID profiles copies data from chunks with the old profile to the chunks with the new profile. Old chunk is not modified in place, they are removed after all data is moved to the new chunk.